# an easier way to follow my favorite tags?

Tags: support

I have a few tags that interest me on stackoverflow. currently I have to view each tag separately to find new questions or unanswered questions that I might be able to help with.

seems like there should be a link for my favorite tags to let me view them together as new, unanswered etc, so that I can see any new or unanswered questions in my favorite tags. currently I find myself keeping several browser tabs open at once to easily check for new or unanswered questions in each of the tags that interest me

Comment: Search for `intags: mine is:q` to get a search result page with questions in your favorited tags. There's other search parameters you can use to check for unanswered as well, such as `hasaccepted: no`.

Comment: See also [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in the help center.

Comment: thanks all intags:mine is:q answers:0 does what I was looking for

Comment: If you are using the [new navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released), you can also set your favorite tags and select filter:favorite tags. Then you can see new and unanswered questions using the tabs on top.